# List of Lists to string repeat

Tags: list, repeat

I've data like this. x is a list below.

`['197056942', '91004902', ['104608942', '95134582'], '91967062']`

Expected result should be:

`197056942|91004902|104608942|91967062
197056942|91004902|95134582|91967062`

I've tried to use `zip` but unable to get the right result. Its truncating the data.

`zip(*x)
[('1', '9', '104608942', '9'), ('9', '1', '95134582', '1')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solved your problem. It was very difficult than I thought.
Here is my Python code.

```
input = ['1','2','3','4',['5','6','7'],'8','9',['10','11'],'12']
tmp = [[]]
for i in input:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        tmp = [j+[k] for j in tmp for k in i]
    else:
        tmp = [j+[i] for j in tmp]

output = ["|".join(i) for i in tmp]
```

output:

```
>>> output
['1|2|3|4|5|8|9|10|12',
 '1|2|3|4|5|8|9|11|12',
 '1|2|3|4|6|8|9|10|12',
 '1|2|3|4|6|8|9|11|12',
 '1|2|3|4|7|8|9|10|12',
 '1|2|3|4|7|8|9|11|12']
```

Comment: Thanks for getting this. I wasnt close to this at all. Lastly I will add 
`for i in output:
  print i`
that should convert it back to rows instead of List.